# best way to validate ownership with HMABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have three models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  has_many :other_itmes
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :other_items

  validate :validate_other_item_ownership
  def validate_other_item_ownership
    if
      (user_ids = OtherItem.where(id: other_item_ids).pluck(:user_id).uniq).present? &&
        (user_ids.size > 1 || user_ids.first != user_id)
    then
      errors.add(:other_item_ids, 'Other Items must belong to same user as Item')
    end
  end
end

class OtherItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items

  validate :validate_item_ownership
  def validate_item_ownership
    if
      (user_ids = Item.where(id: item_ids).pluck(:user_id).uniq).present? &&
        (user_ids.size > 1 || user_ids.first != user_id)
    then
      errors.add(:item_ids, 'Items must belong to same user as Other Item')
    end
  end
end
```

And two controllers like this:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @item = Item.find params[:id]
    @item.other_item_ids = params[:item][:other_item_ids] #assignline
    @item.save!
  end
end

class OtherItemsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @other_item = OtherItem.find params[:id]
    @other_item.item_ids = params[:other_item][:item_ids] #assignline
    @other_item.save!
  end
end
```

The Problem now is that ActiveRecord already saves the items on `#assignline`, while the call to `#save!` correctly raises `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid` the association is still persisted.

I want the user only to be able to link to items to each other which he owned.

Comment: What about using `accepts_nested_attributes_for`?

Comment: I don't want/need to accept attributes, because I don't update/create any `(other_)items`. All I want to do, is to put multiple `items` into relation to `other_items`, and vice versa. But only relations between models owned by the same user should be allowed (valid)!

Comment: Shouldn't validator return false? Maybe switching from habtm to has_many through could solve this issue. You could put validation on join model then

Comment: no a validator doesn't need to return false, it must add an error and then validation fails. I will try this with `has_many:through` tomorrow, I was hoping to do it without, because I don't need a in between model for anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excellent question! I've got a good answer too ;)

(**TLDR**) Ditch `has_and_belongs_to_many`, create a model on top of the join table, put the validation logic in the join model, and use `has_many :through`.

To demonstrate, let's consider the relationship between Artist and Song, both belonging to User. With the join model and `has_many :through` we'll have these model classes:

```
class Artist
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :artist_songs
  has_many :songs, through: :artist_songs
end

class Song
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :artist_songs
  has_many :artists, through: :artist_songs
end

class ArtistSong
  belongs_to :artist
  belongs_to :song
end
```

This is will significantly clean up your validation logic, just add it in one place:

```
class ArtistSong
  #...
  validate :ownership
private
  def ownership
    unless artist.user_id == song.user_id
      errors[:base] << 'artist and song must belong to same user'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
class ArtistsController
  def update
    @artist = current_user.artists.find params[:id]
    @artist.update artist_params
  end
private
  def artist_params
    params.require(:artist).permit(:name, song_ids: [])
  end
end
```

Note: Looks like Rails is doing a `save!` on the join model. This means if the validation fails (just on `ArtistSong`, not `Artist`) it will raise an exception instead of return false. This should only ever happen to malicious users, so no worries.

I rarely use HABTM. Having a model for the join table gives so much more flexibility. For example, you could add a position field and do something like:

```
class Artist
  #...
  has_many :artist_songs, order: -> {'position asc'}
  #...
end
```